# Split Series of tuples into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series of tuples of the form `('Name', Number)`, and I would like to split them into two columns, one being the name, the other being the number.

I'd like to end up with something like this:

```
Tuple                   Name          Number
('Scott Smith', 56)     Scott Smith   56
('Anna Frank', 100)     Anna Frank    100
('Seth Morris', 32)     Seth Morris   32
```

I've tried a few iterations of splitting strings, applying a lambda function, etc, and can't seem to get this simple process right.

Comment: You should probably research ‘unpacking tuples in Python’. It is an easy way to access the items within a tuple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct a new dataframe and assign back to dataframe

sample `df`:

```
               Tuple
0  (Scott Smith, 56)
1  (Anna Frank, 100)
2  (Seth Morris, 32)

df_final = df.assign(**pd.DataFrame(df.Tuple.tolist(), columns=['Name','Number']))

Out[170]:
               Tuple         Name  Number
0  (Scott Smith, 56)  Scott Smith      56
1  (Anna Frank, 100)   Anna Frank     100
2  (Seth Morris, 32)  Seth Morris      32
```

Answer (score 0):

First, convert the series to a dataframe with [`to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html). Then you can use `zip` to assign the new columns:

```
df = s.to_frame('Tuple')
df['Name'], df['Number'] = zip(*df['Tuple'])
```